# How to center a drop down menu under the parent?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make everything almost everything width related to use percentage so it's more adaptable to different resolutions but I'm having issues with my dropdown menus. The drop down isn't centered with the parent and I would like the drop down to be right under the parent and not wider than the parent.

Here's my css for the dropdown

```
ul.news{

display: table-cell;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: ;
}

ul li.news{
float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
background:#313131;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
 }

ul li.news2{
float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
background:#313131;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
 }


ul li a.news{

    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
color: white;
    background:#313131;
    text-decoration: none ;

}
ul li a.news:hover{

text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background:#703f70;

}
ul li ul.news{

width: 32%;
display: none ;

}
ul li.news:hover ul{

float: center;
opacity: .87;
position: absolute;
    display: block; /* display the dropdown */

}
```

Here's the html

```
    <table border="1" width="99%" align="center" bordercolor="#181818" bgcolor="#181818">
<tr>

<td align="center" width="32%" bordercolor="#313131" bgcolor="#313131">
<font size="5" color="#5be5e5">
<b>
    <ul class="news"> 
        <li class="news">5/19/2014
</font>
<br>
<font size="3">
(Hover Over)
</font>
<br>
    <ul class="news">
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Added an arrow pointing down grapic by the Content Page item on the navigation bar to show it has drop-down content.</li>
            <br> 
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Added a Credit Archive.</li> 
            <br>
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Added more of my own grapics. Some parts of the images were grabbed from websites and credit has been given on the Info Page in the Credit Archive.</li>
            <br>  
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Have a great time!</li> 
        </ul>
</li> 
</font>
</td>

<td width="1%">
</td>

<td align="center" width="32%" bordercolor="#313131" bgcolor="#313131">
<font size="5" color="#5be5e5">
<b>
    <ul class="news"> 
        <li class="news">5/18/2014
</font>
<br>
<font size="3">
(Hover Over)
</font>
<br>
    <ul class="news">
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Replaced some of the placeholders with my own images.</li>
            <br> 
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Edited the News Bulletin slightly.</li> 
            <br> 
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Edited Eeveeislegendary a little.</li> 
        </ul>
</li> 
</font>
</td>

<td width="1%">
</td>

<td align="center" width="32%" bordercolor="#313131" bgcolor="#313131">
<font size="5" color="#5be5e5">
<b>
    <ul class="news"> 
        <li class="news">5/16/2014
</font>
<br>
<font size="3">
(Hover Over)
</font>
<br>
    <ul class="news">
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Added Images! The images you see are only placeholders and will be replaced soon.</li>
            <br> 
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Even more colors!</li> 
            <br>
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Added a small pointless website I made called "Eevee Is Best Legendary".</li>
            <br>
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Edited the navigation bar.
            <br>
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Changed About Page to Info Page.
            <br>
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Moved content from Contact Page and Archive Page to Info Page.
            <br>
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Edited the News Bulletin.
            <br>
        <li class="news2"><font size="5" color="#b266b2">-</font> <font size="5"> Edited the Random Button and the buttons for the poll.
        </ul>
</li> 
</font>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Here's a live example.

http://jsfiddle.net/yU9tp/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZbndV/

Comment: This is not the standard way to write html. Don't use `<font>` in html. Describe the `font-family` in css. Try to add negative margin for your drop-down.

Comment: Sorry Atal this was the way I was taught and I'm still pretty new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `align:center` from your `td` tags, that is the main problem here. Then just adjust the borders and padding/etc as needed.

Comment: Although this helps the problem it causes the text in the parent to be aligned to the left I might be blind and not realize how to fix that but I was wondering if you could help.